# Which file contains a list of the following variables?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Within ../android/app/build.gradle, there is a section that looks like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
  }
}
```

Now, `flutter.minSdkVersion` seems to be a variable located in which file within my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to `\android\local.properties`

Then add

```
flutter.minSdkVersion = 26 // the version is up to your needs.
flutter.targetSdkVersion = 32
```

After that return to `defaultConfig` of `build.gradle` and call it like this :

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Don't forget to launch a `flutter clean` `flutter pub get` and then `flutter run`

Answer (score 1):

It is the default values flutter takes.

You should updates these as per needed. For latest flutter android build, it should be

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
  }
}
```